# Regex to deny special norwegian letters in friendly url - modx

Tags: php, regex, modx, modx-revolution

I'm developing a page using modx revolution. It's a complete cms with a lot of built in functions. If I create a page in the manager it will automatically produce a friendly url for me pointing to that page.

The problem is that is does not deny the special characters we have in Norway, æøå (and uppercase ÆØÅ).

The system got a built in regex-pattern to strip the url for most bad characters, but I need the experession to strip æøå and ÆØÅ too.

The pattern looks like this:

```
/[\0\x0B\t\n\r\f\a&=+%#<>"~:`@\?\[\]\{\}\|\^'\\]/
```

Can anyone use their magic regex-knowledge to include these 6 letters? I am totally green at regex, and simply adding the letters in there did not seem to work.

PS: Please don't use the common "boo, don't use regex for this" here. The pattern is there for a reason, and i don't want to mess around with the core if we have to upgrade modx (which is pretty likely to happen sooner or later).

Comment: Since modx is written in php, I added the php tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Unicode. I don't know modx, but since its written in php, I hope it uses php preg regular expressions.

```
/[\0\x0B\t\n\r\f\a&=+%#<>"~:`@\?\[\]\{\}\|\^'\\\x{00C6}\x{00E6}\x{00C5}\x{00E5}\x{00D8}\x{00F8}]/u
```

The `u` modifier tells php to use unicode matching mode, it then interprets the regular expression as unicode string.

`\x{00C6}` is the Unicode character Æ

Please check the code of the other characters by yourself to ensure I didn't made a mistake while looking them up.

See [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) for the unicode usage in php

[Unicode.org](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) for the code point

Answer (score 1):

MODX actually has a system setting where you can define a custom transliteration class: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/friendly_alias_translit_class

However the docs are a bit sparse on how you might implement this. There is an existing package built by one of the core developers which supports alias transliteration for German and Russian, but you can easily add Norwegian or any other language to its configuration:

http://modx.com/extras/package/translit